# How to Separate HTML Response

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using FConnect in my app. After the user logs in to his/her Facebook account I am getting his/her information as:

```
{
    "id":"###########",
    "name":"Vishnu Gupta",
    "first_name":"Vishnu",
    "last_name":"Gupta",
    "link":"facebook a/c link id=#######",
    "education":[{"school":{"id":"######","name":"st.joseph"},"type":"High School"}],
    "gender":"male","email":"##########",
    "timezone":5.5,
    "locale":"en_US",
    "verified":true,
    "updated_time":"2010-11-27T10:10:25+0000"
}
```

I want to store user's information in database. To do that, I have to separate the user's information that is id, name, and email.

I tried using `componentsSeparatedByString` method but I do not understand how to retrieve the information in an array.

Can anyone help me????

Comment: please edit this post again,
Select the code part from cursor and press `ctrl+K`

Answer (score 1):

The response you are getting is in JSON Format which basically have response in Array & Dictionary.

You will be getting this data in Dictionary..so you can access it by using the key value..

NSLog(@"%@",[NSDictionaryObject valueforkey:@"id"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDictionaryObject valueforkey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDictionaryObject valueforkey:@"first_name"]);

Hope this will surely work for you.....

Answer (score 0):

ya.....its corrrect.In detail:
Add JSON SDK then write the below  code

SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init]; 
            NSDictionary *returnObject = [json objectWithString:InfoName];
NSString @id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[returnObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
 same for name ,email.

then Add these objects to Array and release the json

JSOn is good to use for "key-value' pair parsing.